# Error 3021: No Current Record when trying to edit a value in a column of a table through forms

Tags: ms-access

I'm following this tutorial to create a add/subtract button that amends the 'Qty_Avail' value of a Stock table
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88erYOa8cmg

```
Private Sub cmdIN_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Select Qty_Avail from Stock where ID_Item =' " & Me.ID_Item & " ' ")

With rst
    .Edit
    !Qty_Avail = !Qty_Avail + Nz(Me.Quantity, 0)
    .Update
End With
Me.QOH.Requery
Me.Quantity = "'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *RecordsetClone* - faster and updates at once:

```vb
Private Sub cmdIN_Click()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

    Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
    
    With rst
        ' Locate current record.
        .Bookmark = Me.Bookmark
        ' Edit the record.
        .Edit
        !Qty_Avail.Value = !Qty_Avail.Value + Nz(Me!Quantity.Value, 0)
        .Update
        .Close
    End With

    Me!Quantity.Value = 0   ' Or = Null
    
End Sub
```